# Deactivating duplicate rules then redeploying as active does not activate duplicate rules

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, duplicate-management

I ran into this situation:

I have duplicate rules in a sandbox. I deactivated them manually. In my local code repository, I have the duplicate rules version controlled in `package.xml`:

```
    <types>
        <members>Account.Rule1</members>
        <members>Account.Rule2</members>
        <name>DuplicateRule</name>
    </types>
```

In the rule definitions themselves, `Account.Rule1.duplicateRule-meta.xml`, they are set to enabled:

```
...
<isActive>true</isActive>
```

When deploying to the sandbox using `sfdx force:source:deploy -x manifest/package.xml`, the deploy succeeds, but the rules stay disabled.

Why does sfdx ignore the deployed duplicate rule status? Is this something you can't change with metadata deployments? A Salesforce bug? Is it related to me manually editing the rules in the sandbox?

Comment: I've manually changed the rules in the deployed instance but still don't know why/if sfdx can change them